# $scope.$watch() is not picking up service object changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I've written a service for extending the offcanvas library. It's all dandy however I can't seem to get the state object to propagate to my controller.

I'm watching for state changes but nothing seems to happen.

```
(function(){
'strict'
  var state =  {visibility: 'HIDDEN'};
  var closeWidth = 800;

  var defaultSettings = {
    autoHide: false,
    recalc: true,
    toggle: true,
  }

  var getState = function(){
    return state;
  };

  var show = function (){
    if (state.visibility === 'HIDDEN') $(".navmenu").offcanvas('show');
  };

  var hide = function (){
    if (state.visibility === 'VISIBLE') $(".navmenu").offcanvas('hide');
  };

  var config = function(){
    $(".navmenu").offcanvas(defaultSettings);
  };

  var setListeners = function(element){
    element.on('show.bs.offcanvas', function(){
      state.visibility = 'VISIBLE';
      console.log(getState());
    });

    element.on('hide.bs.offcanvas', function(){
      state.visibility = 'HIDDEN';
      console.log(getState());
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
      if ($( document ).width() > 900) hide();
    });
  }

angular.module("offCanvasService",[])

.service('OffCanvasService', function(){
//console.log($scope);

  return {
    config:config,
    hide:hide,
    show:show,
    setListeners:setListeners,
    toggle:function(){
      $(".navmenu").offcanvas('toggle');
    },
    getState:getState
 };
});


})();

(function(){
'strict'
  angular.module('clockOn')
  .controller('NavItemsController', [ 'OffCanvasService', '$scope',
  function(OffCanvasService,$scope){
    this.state = OffCanvasService.getState();

    $scope.$watch(
      OffCanvasService.getState()
    ,
     function(newValue, oldValue){
       console.log(oldValue);
       console.log(newValue);
       console.log('state has changed');
     }
   );

  this.OffCanvasService = OffCanvasService;

  }]);

})();
```

The Template

```
  <ul class="nav navmenu-nav navbar-nav" mobile-List>
    <li class="nav-item" ng-click='navItemCtrl.OffCanvasService.hide()'><a ng-href="/#/preferences"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" ng-click="logout()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

and the directive

```
(function(){
  angular.module('layout-components',[])

  .directive('menuItems', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: "../views/menu-item.html",
      controller: 'NavItemsController',
      controllerAs: 'navItemCtrl'
    }
 })

.directive('canvaseMenu', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "../views/canvase-menu.html",
    controller: 'NavMenuController',
    controllerAs: 'NavMenuController'
  }
});
})();
```

Comment: can you try ```$scope.$watch(function(){return OffCanvasService.getState()}, function(newValue, Oldvalue){})```

Comment: Yeah I have that was one of the first things I tried. It' important I get this working because I need to display different information based on the current offcanvas status

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$scope.$watch(
      OffCanvasService.getState()
    ,
```

with

```
$scope.$watch(
      OffCanvasService.getState
    ,
```

From the documentation, the watchExpression must be

> string: Evaluated as expression
>
> function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.

Comment: I've tried that too but still get nothing. Thanks though

Comment: can you also try passing true as the 3rd parameter to the $watch call?

Comment: unfortunately nothing. I'm stumped. Is it possible that I've written the service incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my functions to within the service declaration and wrap the getter function in a promise. I'm pretty sure there's a better solution if somebody has one

New Service

```
(function(){
'use strict'
angular.module("offCanvasService",[])

.service('OffCanvasService', function($q){

var self = this;

this.state =  {visibility: 'HIDDEN'};
this.closeWidth = 800;

this.defaultSettings = {
  autoHide: false,
  recalc: true,
  toggle: true,
};

this.getState = function(){
  var deffered = $q.defer()

    if(typeof self.state !== 'undefined') {
      deffered.resolve(self.state);
    } else {
      deffered.reject('state is undefined');
    }

  return deffered.promise;
};

this.show = function (){
  if (self.state.visibility === 'HIDDEN') $(".navmenu").offcanvas('show');
};

this.hide = function (){
  if (self.state.visibility === 'VISIBLE') $(".navmenu").offcanvas('hide');
};

this.config = function(){
 $(".navmenu").offcanvas(self.defaultSettings);
};

this.setListeners = function(element){
  element.on('show.bs.offcanvas', function(){
    self.state.visibility = 'VISIBLE';
    self.getState().then(function(response){
    });
  });

  element.on('hide.bs.offcanvas', function(){
    self.state.visibility = 'HIDDEN';
    self.getState().then(function(response){
    });
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($( document ).width() > 900) self.hide();
  });
}

return {
  config:self.config,
  hide:self.hide,
  show:self.show,
  setListeners:self.setListeners,
  toggle:function(){
    $(".navmenu").offcanvas('toggle');
  },
  getState:self.getState
};
});


})();
```